# Configuration mondb with codeigniter

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter

I have face error

> The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled

how to resolve? this error comes when i configure using *codeigniter*.

Comment: check you php.ini and remove MongoDB PECL if you don't need it

Comment: i have not added in php.ini  MongoDB PECL